# Find the mode of a row and a column of a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, random

This is what I need to do:

Declare a 5 X 5 array of integers and fill it with random numbers from 1 to 10. Print it row by row. AFTER the array has been filled, ask the user to enter a row and print the mode of that row. Then, ask the user to enter a column and print the mode of that column. Be sure the user knows whether the first row/column is 0 or 1. Check the input and repeatedly prompt until a valid row/column is entered.

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

  int randNumbers [5][5];
  int i,j;
  int row,col;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           randNumbers[i][j]= rand() % 10 + 1;
   }
 }

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           printf("%3i ", randNumbers[i][j]);
    }
    // move to the next line
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("\n");

  printf("Enter a row (0-4): ");
  scanf("%i", &row);

  while (row > 4 || row < 0) {
      printf("Enter a valid row number: ");
      scanf("%i", &row);
  }



  return 0;
}
```

I printed the random numbers and asked the user to enter a row but I don't know how to find the mode.

Comment: What do you mean by mode ?

Comment: The value that appears most frequently in a data set.

Comment: Consider what is being asked for. You need to identify each unique value and count how many times that value appears in the row or column yes? Think about and make an attempt at describing what you would if you were working the problem with a pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to help you, but here's what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int mode(int a[], int len);

int main(void) {

  int randNumbers [5][5];
  int i,j;
  int row,col;
  char RorC[6];
  int elementsofrow[5];  // a new array to save one row numbers
  int elementsofcol[5]; // a new array to save one column numbers
  int numofmode;
  int len;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           randNumbers[i][j]= rand() % 10 + 1;
   }
 }

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           printf("%3d ", randNumbers[i][j]);
    }
    // move to the next line
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("\n");
    
    // mode number that is from row or colum.
  printf("Row or Column: ");
  scanf("%s", RorC);
  
  // if the input is Column
  if(strcmp(RorC, "Column")==0){
    printf("Enter a Column (0-4): ");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    while (col > 4 || col < 0) {
        printf("Enter a valid Column number: ");
        scanf("%d", &col); }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        elementsofcol[i] = randNumbers[i][col];     //copy all numbers in that Column to elementsofcol
    }
    int len = sizeof(elementsofcol) / sizeof(int);
    numofmode=mode(elementsofcol, len);
    printf("The mode in Column %d is: %d", col, numofmode);
    
  }
    else if(strcmp(RorC, "Row")==0){    //if the input is Row
    printf("Enter a row (0-4): ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    while (row > 4 || row < 0) {
        printf("Enter a valid row number: ");
        scanf("%d", &row);}
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        elementsofrow[i] = randNumbers[row][i];       //copy all numbers in that row to elementsofrow
        }
    int len = sizeof(elementsofrow) / sizeof(int);
    numofmode=mode(elementsofrow, len);
    printf("The mode in row %d is: %d", row, numofmode);
    }
  
  





  return 0;
}

int mode(int elementsarray[], int len) {
    
   int maxValue = 0; 
   int maxCount = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      int count = 0;
      
      for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
         if (elementsarray[j] == elementsarray[i])
         ++count;
      }
      
      if (count > maxCount) {
         maxCount = count;
         maxValue = elementsarray[i];
      }
   }

   return maxValue;
}
```

Here is the reference to find the mode number in an array:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/learn_c_by_examples/mode_program_in_c.htm

Comment: It helped me so much. Thanks!